# Product (Agent) differentiation in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I am currently building a model of a factory in AnyLogic and I have not yet figured out how to differentiate different products through the factory flow. I am modelling cycle times using delay but I want the cycle times to de different depending on which product that the machine works on. 
I am very greatful for any tips on how to do this!

/Christoffer

Answer (score 0):

A basic concept of anylogic is agents. learning about them is essential to use anylogic. (find more info here [Anylogic doc](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/agentbased/Agent.html)
The basic idea is that you represent your products as agents, with parameters, functions, statechart etc.
 
Eg. you could have an agent Type "Car". with parameters like:

```
int number_of_wheels = 4;
String carType = "sportscar";
```

[image]
[image]

When processing them with the eg. the "process modeling library" you extract the info from your agents. This is done with the keyword: "agent" eg. agent.carType. you can use that info to determine a delay function:

```
int delay_function(Car agent){
    if(agent.carType.equals("truck")
        return 5;
    else if(agent.carType.equals("sportscar")
        return 10;
}
```

when you enter a delay, where you want to specify the delay time. You can use the function like: `delay_function(agent)`

[image]